# Does this piece of clothing have a specific name?

Tags: culture

Does this piece of clothing have a specific name? I mean the scarf (?) that is linked to her cuffs.

[image]

Comment: This is likely a dance shawl but the design is a bit atypical of what you see irl

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a normal dance shawl, though they are more common with an Arabian clothing style and for dancing without a partner.

[image]

Something similar to - but not quite like - this, is a hagomoro.
But those float on their own.

[image]